# Could not find any column information for table

Tags: odbc, netsuite

Any have this similar problem

> -ERROR [HY000] [NetSuite][ODBC 32bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Could not find any column information for
>   table:item_location_map.[10131]
>
> -ERROR [HY000] [NetSuite][ODBC 32bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Could not find any column information for
>   table:locations.[10131]
>
> -ERROR [HY000] [NetSuite][ODBC 32bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Could not find any column information for
>   table:Transactions.[10131]
>
> -ERROR [HY000] [NetSuite][ODBC 32bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Could not find any column information for table:items.[10131]

I check the Answer id:36471,44264 and it was not useful to me.

Any have idea?

Comment: what was your query ?

Comment: Also, Which role are you using?

Comment: Role Administrator. The query is several for exaple: Select loc.location_extid As ID_Cont, it.ITEM_EXTID As SKU, NVL(st.ON_HAND_COUNT,0) As SKU_Qty, nvl(st.in_transit_count,0) InTransit, NVL(ON_ORDER_COUNT,0) OnOrder, NVL(st.available_count,0) Available, NVL(REORDER_POINT,0) ReorderLevel, NVL(st.PREF_STOCK_LEVEL,0) StockLevel From item_location_map st  INNER JOIN Locations loc on st.location_id = loc.location_id And st.LOCATION_ID in (281,284,287,290,293) INNER JOIN items it ON st.ITEM_ID = it.ITEM_ID  And it.ITEM_EXTID IS NOT NULL and it.TYPE_NAME = 'Inventory Item'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetSuite told me that was a mistake on their part, they corrected my intance